# Bitmap conversion: Creating bitmap that excludes transparent sides from transparent bitmap

Tags: java, android, image-processing, bitmap

I have a set of bitmaps. They are all transparent to some extent, and I don't know in advance which parts are transparent. I would like to create a new bitmap out of the original bitmap that excludes the transparent parts, but in a square. I think this image explains it:

[image]

I know how to create a bitmap out of a existing bitmap, but I don't know how to find out which part is transparent and how to use that to achieve my goal.

This is how I plan on doing this:

```
public Bitmap cutImage(Bitmap image) {
        Bitmap newBitmap = null; 

        int width = image.getWidth(); 
        int height = image.getHeight(); 

        newBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); 

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(newBitmap); 

        //This is where I need to find out correct values of r1 and r1.

        Rect r1 = new Rect(?, ?, ?, ?);
        Rect r2 = new Rect(?, ?, ?, ?);

        canvas.drawBitmap(image, r1, r2, null);

        return newBitmap; 
     }
```

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

**EDIT:**

I got it work using the following algorithm to find left, right, top and bottom values:

```
private int x1;
private int x2;
private int y1;
private int y2;

private void findRectValues(Bitmap image)
{
    for(int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); x++)
    {
        for(int y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); y++)
        {
            if(image.getPixel(x, y) != Color.TRANSPARENT)
            {
                System.out.println("X1 is: " + x);
                x1 = x;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(x1 != 0)
            break;

    }

    for(int x = image.getWidth()-1; x > 0; x--)
    {
        for(int y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); y++)
        {
            if(image.getPixel(x, y) != Color.TRANSPARENT)
            {
                System.out.println("X2 is: " + x);
                x2 = x;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(x2 != 0)
            break;

    }

    for(int y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); y++)
    {
        for(int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); x++)
        {
            if(image.getPixel(x, y) != Color.TRANSPARENT)
            {
                System.out.println("Y1 is: " + y);
                y1 = y;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(y1 != 0)
            break;

    }

    for(int y = image.getHeight()-1; y > 0; y--)
    {
        for(int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); x++)
        {
            if(image.getPixel(x, y) != Color.TRANSPARENT)
            {
                System.out.println("Y2 is: " + y);
                y2 = y;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(y2 != 0)
            break;

    }
}
```

Comment: hi, in my application i also want to crop transparent pixels please help me how to remove transparent pixels from bitmap

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If all the images you want to crop are more or less in the center of the original canvas, I guess you could so something like this:

1. Start from each border working your way inwards the image searching for non-transparent pixels
2. Once you've found the top-left pixel and the right-bottom, you'll have your desired target.
3. Copy the image as you please

Now, the question remains is what you consider a transparent pixel. Does alpha trasparency counts? if so, how much alpha until you decide it's transparent enough to be cut from the image?

Comment: By transparent pixel I mean pixels with alpha 0, completely transparent. The images I want to crop aren't always going to be in the center of the original canvas. They might even be in the lower right corner. Does this affect your answer?

Comment: I'd say search for the first from the top left, then left most, rightmost, and bottom. On the example given, the top left and bottom right would cut off quite a bit of the image.

Answer (score 6):

i think this is a bit more efficient and it works great for me

```
public Bitmap cropBitmapToBoundingBox(Bitmap picToCrop, int unusedSpaceColor) {
    int[] pixels = new int[picToCrop.getHeight() * picToCrop.getWidth()];
    int marginTop = 0, marginBottom = 0, marginLeft = 0, marginRight = 0, i;
    picToCrop.getPixels(pixels, 0, picToCrop.getWidth(), 0, 0,
            picToCrop.getWidth(), picToCrop.getHeight());

    for (i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++) {
        if (pixels[i] != unusedSpaceColor) {
            marginTop = i / picToCrop.getWidth();
            break;
        }
    }

    outerLoop1: for (i = 0; i < picToCrop.getWidth(); i++) {
        for (int j = i; j < pixels.length; j += picToCrop.getWidth()) {
            if (pixels[j] != unusedSpaceColor) {
                marginLeft = j % picToCrop.getWidth();
                break outerLoop1;
            }
        }
    }

    for (i = pixels.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (pixels[i] != unusedSpaceColor) {
            marginBottom = (pixels.length - i) / picToCrop.getWidth();
            break;
        }
    }

    outerLoop2: for (i = pixels.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        for (int j = i; j >= 0; j -= picToCrop.getWidth()) {
            if (pixels[j] != unusedSpaceColor) {
                marginRight = picToCrop.getWidth()
                        - (j % picToCrop.getWidth());
                break outerLoop2;
            }
        }
    }

    return Bitmap.createBitmap(picToCrop, marginLeft, marginTop,
            picToCrop.getWidth() - marginLeft - marginRight,
            picToCrop.getHeight() - marginTop - marginBottom);
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly on android 4 - .., have tested on 3 devises. Thanks for your code, it helped

Answer (score 0):

To find the non-transparent area of your bitmap, iterate across the bitmap in x and y and find the min and max of the non-transparent region. Then crop the bitmap to those co-ordinates.

```
Bitmap CropBitmapTransparency(Bitmap sourceBitmap)
{
    int minX = sourceBitmap.getWidth();
    int minY = sourceBitmap.getHeight();
    int maxX = -1;
    int maxY = -1;
    for(int y = 0; y < sourceBitmap.getHeight(); y++)
    {
        for(int x = 0; x < sourceBitmap.getWidth(); x++)
        {
            int alpha = (sourceBitmap.getPixel(x, y) >> 24) & 255;
            if(alpha > 0)   // pixel is not 100% transparent
            {
                if(x < minX)
                    minX = x;
                if(x > maxX)
                    maxX = x;
                if(y < minY)
                    minY = y;
                if(y > maxY)
                    maxY = y;
            }
        }
    }
    if((maxX < minX) || (maxY < minY))
        return null; // Bitmap is entirely transparent

    // crop bitmap to non-transparent area and return:
    return Bitmap.createBitmap(sourceBitmap, minX, minY, (maxX - minX) + 1, (maxY - minY) + 1);
}
```